# How do I stop a stock split?

Tags: stocks, stock-split

If a stock split is coming soon and the company did not bother to consult shareholders before deciding to do the stock split, do I have the right to resist the split? How can I stop the stock split? Do I have to sue the company? I don't want any forward splits or reverse splits because they are useless to me. Stock splits also needlessly complicate my record-keeping.

Comment: I kind of feel like this is one of those questions that if you have to ask, you aren't going to have the power to do anything anyway. In short, you convince the board of directors that they are making a mistake. You better own a bunch of shares. Like a whole, whole, whole bunch, because otherwise they really arent going to bother to listen to you...

Comment: Probably something along the lines of: sue them in court and the court will make them reimburse you for the damage you suffered (which is $0)

Comment: To add to R: You should definitely have a blocking minority - 5%. Also, noone cares whether YOU have been asked - if the split has been authorized BEFORE you got the shares.

Comment: LOL.  Gotta like the idea of suing them in court because the stock split "complicates my record-keeping."  ;->)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a stockholder you get to vote for board members and other corporate actions. You might even get a chance to vote on a stock split in some situations.

However, unless you own a ton of shares you will likely be outvoted because this is such a routine thing that most stockholders wouldn't and realistically shouldn't care about.

You can sue anyone you like, but in this case there is almost zero chance you would win because this is a standard practice and they don't owe you more say in the matter than the number of voting shares you own.